# Conditional Combobox in XML

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xhtml

I'm working with a cd catalog in XML and i have to make a combobox with some attributes of the cds, like release year or country.

How can i do it?

I tried adding [] on the options, like this:

```
<select name="Cds">
<option value="catalog/cd[country='USA']"</option>
</select>
```

This is the xml i'm working with http://www.w3schools.com/xml/cd_catalog.xml

I want to create a combobox that have as options the cds that are from USA.

Comment: Please post your XML input (a minimized, but complete example) and the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need something like this:

```
<select name="Cds">
    <!-- iterate over the relevant input elements -->
    <xsl:for-each select="CATALOG/CD[COUNTRY = 'USA']">
        <!-- for each one, build an option element -->
        <option value="{TITLE}">
            <xsl:value-of select="TITLE"/>
        </option>
    </xsl:for-each>
</select>
```

Note that, when building the `value` attribute, expressions must be inside curly brackets `{}`.

Answer (score 0):

XML is case-sensitive. `<COUNTRY>` and `<country>` are different tags.

Comment: Thanks for the obervation, but that's not why is not working. I thinks its related with the syntax of the "option value"

Comment: Okay, then show us the real XSLT code.  I'll make one more "observation".  If you want to use XSLT to insert a value into an attribute, you have to use an attribute value template -- i.e. curly braces.